How to Pause and Resume Animation on Mouse Events in Unity for a Flick Goal Game?
I'm developing a flick goal game in Unity where the player character's animation needs to run, pause, and resume based on specific mouse events. Here's what I want to achieve:

The animation should pause when the player presses the left mouse button (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)).

The animation should wait for the player to drag the mouse.

The animation should continue (i.e., the player hits the ball) when the mouse button is released after dragging.


I have an Animator component attached to my player character and a ball object that needs to be hit. How can I implement this animation control logic in a script?
Here's what I have so far:
if(_isShooting) {       // neu banh chua vao luoi hoac trung thu mon, khung thanh thi banh duoc phep bay voi van toc dang co
            if( _enableTouch && !_isInTutorial ) {
                if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {           // touch phase began
                    mouseBegin(Input.mousePosition);
                    _playerController.OnMouseDownAnimationStart();
                }
                else if( Input.GetMouseButton(0) ) {            
                    mouseMove(Input.mousePosition);
                }
                else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {    // touch ended
                    mouseEnd();
                }
            }
            if(_isShoot) {
                Vector3 speed = _ballParent.InverseTransformDirection(_ball.velocity);
                speed.z = _zVelocity;
                _ball.velocity = _ballParent.TransformDirection(speed);
            }
        }

 public void OnMouseDownAnimationStart()
{
    // Handle the start of the animation
    animator.speed = 0;
}


This is not unityscript, please remove the tag.

i would do this.
bool hold=false;
Vector3 startPoint=new Vector3();
void Update{

    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
        if(!hold){
            startPoint=Input.mousePosition;
            hold=true;
        }
        //change speed is the speed you want your animation to stop.
        //this looks much better than just stopping it.
        animator.speed=mathf.Lerp(animator.speed,0,changeSpeed*Time.DeltaTime);

        }else{

            if(hold)
            {

                hold=false;

                //do whatever you want with drag data here
                //this is drag vector
                Vector3 dragData=Input.mousePosition-startPoint;
            }

        animator.speed=Mathf.Lerp(animator.speed,1,changeSpeed*Time.DeltaTime);

}

